# rotation of file in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I need to write rotation of files shell script. I have following format data in a target directory(/backup/store_id/dates_folders)

Like :

cd /backup/

drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Mar 25 12:30 44

drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Mar 25 12:30 45

drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Mar 25 12:30 48

drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Mar 25 12:30 49

cd /backup/44/

drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 25 12:30 22032014

drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 25 12:30 23032014

drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 25 12:30 24032014

drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 25 12:30 25032014

now 44 (store_id) contain four dates folders. I want each store_id( like 44 folder) contain only three recent dates folder like 23,24,25 & 22 should be deleted. Please help me how to write in shell script. Please give me some hint

Comment: Look at using `find` with the `-mtime` or `-ctime` options

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
cd /backup && ls -d */ | while read storeId; do rm -r `ls -r $storeId | tail -3`; done
```

I assume here that directory names are more important than their timestamps...
If that is not the case, you should use `ls -tr` instead of `ls -r`, to let `ls` command sort on timestamps...